# Social media's like and unlike data model in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

Imagine there is a social network and here is a table for storing the like (favorite) action and unlike that is deleting from this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post_likes(
  post_id timeuuid,
  liker_id uuid, //liker user_id
    like_time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((post_id) ,liker_id, like_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (like_time DESC);
```

The above table has problem in Cassandra because when `liker_id` is the first `clustering_key`, we can't sort by the second clustering key which is `like_time`.

We need to sort our tables data by `like_time`, we use it when a user wants to see who liked this post and we show list of people who liked that post that sorted by time *(`like_time DESC`)*

and we also need to delete (unlike) and we again need to have `post_id` and `liker_id`

**What is your suggestion? How we can sort this table by `like_time`?**

Comment: do you find any solution? :D

Comment: @vahidchakoshy Yes I did! But we are still researching for the best way! You know Cassandra is really great but it is hard to find good references about it! Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @vahidchakoshy Did you use Cassandra for Wisgoon.com?

Comment: i still searching for best solution to storing likes in cassandra . for wisgoon just view page source :D

Comment: we are migrating from redis to cassandra ;)

Comment: @vahidchakoshy We also use Cassandra beside Redis. Cassandra's write and read path is really fast but searching is a problem, We use Solr to search data we need. We designed some data modeling for likes strucher in Cassandra, I will share it here or maybe send it to your email

Comment: thank you, vchakoshy [at] gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*After more researches, I found out this solution:*
Picking the right data model is the hardest part of using Cassandra and here is the solution we found for likes tables in Cassandra, first of all, I have to say Cassandra's [read](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/dml/dml_about_read_path_c.html) and [write](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/WritePathForUsers) path is amazingly fast and you don't need to be worry about writing  on your Cassandra's tables, you need to **model around your queries** and *remember, data duplication is okay. Many of your tables may repeat the same data.* and do not forget to **spread data evenly around the cluster** and **minimize the number of partitions read**

Since we are using Cassandra which is NoSQL, we know one of the rules in NoSQLs is denormalization and we have to denormalize data and just think about the queries you want to have; Here for the like table data modeling we will have two tables, these tables have mainly focused on the easy read or easier to say **we have focused on queries we want to have**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post_likes(
    post_id timeuuid,
    liker_id uuid, //liker user_id
    like_time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((post_id) ,liker_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post_likes_by_time(
    post_id timeuuid,
    liker_id uuid, //liker user_id
    like_time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((post_id), like_time, liker_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (like_time DESC);
```

When a user like a post, we just insert into both above tables.

---

**why do we have `post_likes_by_time` table?**

In a social network, you should show list of users who liked a post, it is common that you have to sort likes by the `like_time DESC` and since you are going to sort likes by `like_time` you need to have `like_time` as clustering key to be able to sort likes by time.

**Then why do we have `post_likes` table too?**

In the `post_likes_by_time`, our clustering key is `like_time`, we also need to **remove** one like! We can't do that when we sorted data in our table when clustering key is *like_time*. That is the reason we also have `post_likes` table

**Why you could not only have one table and do both actions, sorting and removing on it?**

To delete one like from `post_likes` table we need to provide `user_id` (here liker_id) and `post_id` (together) and in `post_likes_by_time` we have `like_time` as clustering key and we need to sort table by `like_time`, then it should be the first clustering key and the second clustering key could be `liker_id`, and here is the point!  `like_time` is the first clustering key then for selecting or deleting by `liker_id` you also need to provide `like_time`, but you do not have `like_time` most of the times.